# Faking optical size feature using XeLaTeX, fontspec

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, fontsize

Is it possible to approximate fake "optical sizes" with `fontspec` using a font which doesn't have this feature (in my case, Cambria)?

The use case here is that I'm writing a scientific text with lots of in-text `\textsuperscript` and `\textsubscript` which would really benefit from being slightly bolder.

Comment: The short answer is: "no" :)

Comment: The slightly longer answer is that MAYBE with adjusting weight and width just a little you could create something that wasn't terribly ugly on first glance.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected, but for some reason I can't get a minimal working example for `FakeBold` with Cambria. Is this expected?

Comment: See my comment to Henri Menke's answer below: the current default macOS PDF engine fails to render `FakeBold`. Oh well...

Comment: Update: the PDFkit bug appears to have been fixed in the latest macOS update (10.13.4, 17E199).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it is only about the super and subscript, you could redefine those macros to add boldening using PDF literals.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{letltxmacro}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\LetLtxMacro\oldtextsuperscript\textsuperscript
\LetLtxMacro\oldtextsubscript\textsubscript

\newcommand\embolden[1]{%
  \special{pdf:literal 2 Tr 1.0 w}% adjust the 1.0
  #1%
  \special{pdf:literal 0 Tr 0 w}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textsuperscript[1]{%
  \oldtextsuperscript{\embolden{#1}}%
}
\DeclareRobustCommand\textsubscript[1]{%
  \oldtextsubscript{\embolden{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

Hello\textsuperscript{Hello}
World\textsubscript{World}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks, that solves quite nicely my original issue. On the flip side, I've discovered that macOS High Sierra's Preview.app completely fails to render your emboldened sub/superscripts as intended. The fault lies with Preview, though, not with XeLaTeX, because Adobe Reader renders everything correctly.

Comment: @Mathieu — oh, that's a real shame. I'd heard the new PDF rendering engine in macOS was a step backwards...

Comment: Amazingly, this bug appears to have been fixed in the latest macOS update (10.13.4, 17E199). Thanks again.